# Prisma with mongo unable to write to the current primary in a replica set

Tags: mongodb, prisma

I have deployed a mongo database with 3 members in a replica set all locally i.e.

```
example.com:11995 (primary)
example.com:11993
example.com:11992
```

I then connected to the database using prisma specifying the replica set members in the connection string and the replica set

```
mongodb://username:password @example.com:11995,example.com:11993,example.com:11992/database?authSource=database&replicaSet=setName
```

However if the primary changes say from example.com:11995 to example.com:11992 prisma is unable to do any more write operations unless I manually revert back 11995 to be the primary. Is their a way to configure prisma to write to the current primary instead of failing write transactions

I have tried adding write majority to the connection string but the problem still persist

Comment: what `db.runCommand({ hello : 1 })` shows you in the shell?

Comment: @dododo it shows the replica set configuration details i.e memebers current primary etc

Comment: i know, please provide it,